# Is there any ORM tool for sql server 7.0?

Tags: sql-server, orm, sql-server-7

I have a sql server 7.0 database and I will implement a web service above it. How do I access the data without writing any sql query?

Comment: Any constraints on the language?

Comment: Since cost seems to be an issue, I could assume that's why you don't have Sql Server 2008, it might be worth looking at moving to either Sql Express, MySql, SqlLite  or other similar modern database that is dollar free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) to map your object model to the relational database model. NHibernate is free, open source, native .NET and supports SQL Server.

Comment: are you sure that Nhibernate supports sql server 7.0

Answer (score 1):

[LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com) is compatible with SQL Server 7

Comment: sorry I forget to say that it should be free